# What does John want us to believe in John 20:31?

Tags: john

**John 20:31** of the Young's Literal Translation bible says:

> and these have been written that ye may believe that **Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God**, and that **[by] believing [this]** ye may have life in his name.

What does the author of the book of John himself want us to believe?

Is there anything else in the gospel of John about Jesus that **must** be added to this doctrinal statement in order to be a follower of Jesus,  and how would this be supported scripturally?

Comment: Please clarify what you do not understand about the verse.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the verse or the authorial intent of what the Apostle John is writing is not to prove the Trinity or as you say, where's the three in one." John wants us to know who Jesus Christ is?

At Matthew 16:13 Jesus said, "Who do people say that the Son of Man is?" The Apostle Peter answered and said, "Thou art the Christ, the Son of the living God." Jesus answered at verse 17, "Blessed are you, Peter because flesh and blood did not reveal this to you, but My Father in heaven."

Keep in mind that what Peter stated is exactly what John stated at John 10:30, "Thou are the Christ/Messiah the Son of the living God." Note the patter I'm about to present. John 5:17-18, "My Father is working until now, and I Myself am working." vs18, "For this cause therefore the Jews were seeking all the more to kill Him, because(or why?) He not only was breaking the Sabbath, but also was calling God His OWN FATHER, making Himself equal with God."

John 8:58-59, "Jesus said to them, "Truly, truly I say to you, before Abraham was born/sprang into existence, I am." Vs59, "Therefore they/the Jews picked up stones to throw at Him, but Jesus hid Himself and went out of the temple." Question, why did the Jews want to kill Jesus?

John 10:30, "I and the Father are one." Vs31, "The Jews took up stones AGAIN to stone Him." Why? Vs32, "Jesus answered them, I showed you many good works from the Father; for which of them are you stoning Me?"

Verse 33, "The Jews answered Him, For a good work we do not stone You, but for BLASPHEMY; and because You, BEING A MAN, MAKE YOURSELF OUT GOD." John 19:7, "The Jews answered Him, We have a law, and by that law He ought to die because (or why?) He made HIMSELF OUT THE SON OF GOD."

Notice the Jews accuse Jesus of claiming to be God and also claiming to be the Son of God. So why is it blasphemy resulting in death for Jesus to claim to be the Son of God?

Let's go to the trial record at Matthew 26:57-66. The high priest Caiaphas at vs63, "But Jesus kept silent, And the high priest said to Him/Jesus, "I adjure You by the living God, that you tell us whether You are the Christ/Messiah, the Son of God."

The high priest is asking Jesus to "SWEAR" as to His identity. This is where Jesus breaks His silence and says at Luke 22:70, "Yes, I am." Matthew 26:65, "Then the high priest tore his robes saying, "He has blasphemed! What further need do we have of witnesses? Behold, you have now heard the blasphemy; vs66, what do you think?" They answered and said, "He is deserving of death!"

So ask yourself this question? What did Jesus say in all of these instances that caused the Jews to accuse Him of blasphemy resulting in His death? If He did not "blaspheme" in their view why did the Jews quote the law of blasphemy at Leviticus 24:16? They knew exactly what Jesus was claiming right from the start.

Also notice, why would the Jews accuse Jesus of blasphemy for claiming to be the Son of God since they themselves claim to be sons of God? This thread started by quoting John 10:31 which is actually the conclusion of the gospel of John as to the identity of Jesus Christ.

What about the declaration of Thomas at John 20:28? "Thomas answered and said to Him/Jesus Christ not God the Father, "My Lord and my God." Or literally, "The Lord of me and the God of men."

Finally, I do not believe trinitarianism is a REQUIREMENT for salvation. It is the RESULT of salvation, for you cannot know Jesus Christ and somehow miss the fact that He is God. You cannot have experienced the presence of the Holy Spirit of God and somehow miss that He is God.

Romans 8:9-11, "and those who are in the flesh cannot please God. vs9, However you are not in the flesh but in the Spirit, if indeed the Spirit of God dwells in you. But if anyone does not have the Spirit of Christ he does not belong to Him. vs10, And if Christ is in you, though the body is dead because of sin, yet the spirit is alive because of righteousness. "But if the Spirit of Him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you. He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit who indwells you."

Answer (score 0):

> What does John want us to believe in John 20:31?

That is why John says of his Gospel account, that it was: (John 20:31)

John 20:31 of Young's Literal Translation Bible says:

> "And these have been written that ye may believe that Jesus is the
>   Christ, the Son of God, and that [by] believing [this] ye may have
>   life in his name."

So knowledge of God’s Word the Bible and all that it tells us about his Son, Jesus  Christ, is essential to have that life-saving faith.

**Do you have such knowledge?**

So knowing the truth about the only true God and his son  Jesus can lead to eternal life
.
John 17:3  (NKJV)

> 3 "And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true
>   God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent."

John 14:6  (NKJV)

> 6 "Jesus said to him, “I am the way, the truth, and the life. No one
>   comes to the Father except through Me."

How to treat others.

John 13:34-35 (NKJV)

> 34 "A new commandment I give to you, that you love one another; as I
>   have loved you, that you also love one another. 35 By this all will
>   know that you are My disciples, if you have love for one another.”

John the Baptist after hearing and seeing what happened had no doubt the Jesus was the Son of God and that he was sent by God.

John 1:32-34  (NKJV)

> 32 "And John bore witness, saying, “I saw the Spirit descending from
>   heaven like a dove, and He remained upon Him. 33 I did not know Him,
>   but He who sent me to baptize with water said to me, ‘Upon whom you
>   see the Spirit descending, and remaining on Him, this is He who
>   baptizes with the Holy Spirit.’ 34 And I have seen and testified that
>   this is the Son of God.”

On many occasions, Jesus said that he lived in heaven before being born as a human. God transferred the life of Jesus from heaven to the womb of a Jewish virgin  Mary. No human father was involved.

John 3:13  (NKJV)

> 13 No one has ascended to heaven but He who came down from heaven,
>   that is, the Son of Man [a]who is in heaven.

The Word Becomes Flesh

John 1:14  (NKJV)

> 14 "And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we beheld His
>   glory, the glory as of the only begotten of the Father, full of grace
>   and truth."

Jesus the only-begotten Son of God says: "for the Father is greater than I."

John 14:28 (NKJV)

> 28 You have heard Me say to you, ‘I am going away and coming back to
>   you.’ If you loved Me, you would rejoice because [a]I said, ‘I am
>   going to the Father,’ for My Father is greater than I.

Father and Son enjoy close association, possibly for billions of years.

John 3:35  (NKJV)

> 35 The Father loves the Son, and has given all things into His hand.

John 14:31 (NKJV)

> 31 But that the world may know that I love the Father, and as the
>   Father gave Me commandment, so I do. Arise, let us go from here.

What Jesus said and did while on earth helps us to know him as well as the Father, for the Son is a perfect reflection of the Father,(Col. 1:15)

John 14:9  (NKJV)

> 9 "Jesus said to him, “Have I been with you so long, and yet you have
>   not known Me, Philip? He who has seen Me has seen the Father; so how
>   can you say, ‘Show us the Father’?

John 7:16 (NASB)

1

> 6 "So Jesus answered them and said, “My teaching is not Mine, but His
>   who sent Me."

**And everything that is written in the four Gospels.**

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to believe that πιστεύοντες is transitive in this case with an implied demonstrative (this), referring to something other than the preceding clause Ἰησοῦς ἐστιν ὁ Χριστὸς ὁ υἱὸς τοῦ Θεοῦ.  What is actually in Young's Literal Translation is *and that believing ye may have life in his name.*, without any implied words in square brackets.

That having been said, though, it might be worth pointing out that the word for "believe" and "have faith" are the same word in Greek -  πιστεύω (*pisteuō*) - so one could interchange the two terms in just about any translation that has *pisteuō*.  An equally valid reading of John 20:31 would be: *But these things are written, that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that* having faith *ye might have life through his name.* That is brought out in this Greek commentary (in English translation) by Theophylact:

> *But these things are written, that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that believing ye might have life through
> his name.* By these words, John proclaims that he wrote this book not
> for the sake of writing, but for the sake of urging us to believe. For
> faith [πίστις] is the foundation of all good things, and unbelief
> [ἀπιστία] is the source of every evil. And so, John seeks to instill
> in us the faith that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God, in order
> that we might obtain eternal life. For eternal life is given to those
> who believe, but the wrath of God abides on those who do not believe (*PG* 124:1001).